# SQL Server 2012 RAM consumption

Tags: sql-server, memory, perfmon

I'm running SQL Server 2012 (x64) on a Windows 10 (x64) machine with 64GB of RAM. I've allocated 32000MB to SQL Server.  When running a Restore with NORECOVERY, RAM hardly gets used and the job takes upwards of 17 hours. I have what seems to be a near identical setup on a different reporting server that runs the job in ~4hours.

I've taken a look at some perfmon counters and noticed that while target server memory is at 32GB, total server memory hovers around 1GB. From what I understand, this means there is memory pressure on the server, however, total RAM usage on the box stays between 4%-6%.

Any ideas on what could be causing the issue? We've all seen SQL gobble up memory, interesting that I can't get this instance to take any.

FWIW, i've also added the NT Service/MSSQLSERVER to 'Gpedit - lock pages in memory' with no improvement.

I'm starting to lean towards bad RAM or MOBO. However, Windows and BIOS seem to see the RAM fine, and a memtest comes back clean.

Please tell me I'm overlooking something dumb.

Comment: Why are you focusing on memory for a slow restore, which is typically IO bound? Total server memory will naturally be low until the cache is warmed up. A better indicator of memory pressure is when target server is less than the configured max.

Comment: Agree with Dan, I think you are not looking at the right place here. SQL Restore operation reads file from disk and then write to the data file. It usually does not put all of the read page into memory (at least it does not when doing a backup so I presume it will be the same for a restore).
Look at your disk IO perfmon, that may give you a better hint about where your problem is

Comment: I don't think that a restore will pull data into the buffer pool, which would be the primary consumer of memory for SQL Server. If a restore is slow on identical hardware, my first suspicion would be that [Instant File Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-ver15) may not be configured on the slow server. But ultimately, you'd need to look at specific wait types for your session doing the `RESTORE`.

Comment: I'm seeing extremely high BACKUPIO times.  Another confusing element, as the split backup files are stored on a local SSD.